# Can I run CCActionSequence more than one time?

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

I have scene like this:

MyScene : CCScene

MyScene has a property CCButton *myMenu

When I touch myMenu, myMenu runs a CCActionSequence (contains a CCActionCallFunc calling a selector).

It works fine (can call selector in CCActionCallFunc) for the first time I touch myMenu.
But CCActionCallFunc doesn't call the selector for the subsequent requests.

How can i explain about that??? I used cocos2d v3

Example:

In 1st scene I have myMenu set target like this:

```
[self.myMenu setTarget:self selector:@selector(touchMyMenu:)];
```

```
- (void)touchMyMenu:(id)sender {
NSArray *actions = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[CCActionCallFunc actionWithTarget:self selector:@selector(callFunction1)], [CCActionCallFunc actionWithTarget:self selector:@selector(callFunction2)], nil];
CCActionSequence *sequence = [CCActionSequence actionWithArray:actions]; 
[self.myMenu runAction:sequence];
}
```

```
- (void)callFunction1 {
// do something
}
- (void)callFunction2 {
// I used CCDirector to push to 2nd scene
}
```

It works fine the first time I touch myMenu. 
But after that I use CCDirector to pop to 1st scene.
And now i touch again in myMenu but it neither calls callFunction1 nor callFunction2

Comment: does the CCSequence not being called, or just the selector is not fired? you also can put some code here

Comment: @mednevNick

myMenu set target like this:
[self.myMenu setTarget:self selector:@selector(touchMyMenu:)];

- (void)touchMyMenu:(id)sender
{
    NSArray *actions = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[CCActionCallFunc actionWithTarget:self selector:@selector(callFunction1)], [CCActionCallFunc actionWithTarget:self selector:@selector(callFunction2)], nil];
    CCActionSequence *sequence = [CCActionSequence actionWithArray:actions];
    [self.myMenu runAction:sequence];
}

It works fine in the first time I touch in myMenu, but after that it not call to callFunction1 or callFunction2

Comment: looks fine, maybe, you've set `self.myMenu` to `nil` in one of these functions? what about setting a breakpoint inside `-touchMyMenu`?

Comment: @medvedNick: no pieces of code set self.myMenu to nil. when i debug, it runs through -(void)touchMyMenu normally but not call to Function1 and Function2

Comment: then I do not know whats wrong :( you can double-check, what `callFunction`s do, maybe they set menu to disabled or so. Comment all code inside them and put `NSLog` there for debug. Btw, you can use `@[object1, object2]` instead of `[NSArray arrayWithObjects:object1, object2, nil]`

Answer (score 0):

Since you're calling the selectors in the same class (`self` is the target), instead of doing this:

```
- (void)touchMyMenu:(id)sender {
NSArray *actions = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
    [CCActionCallFunc actionWithTarget:self selector:@selector(callFunction1)],
    [CCActionCallFunc actionWithTarget:self selector:@selector(callFunction2)], nil];
CCActionSequence *sequence = [CCActionSequence actionWithArray:actions]; 
[self.myMenu runAction:sequence];
}
```

... you can simply call the selectors directly:

```
- (void)touchMyMenu:(id)sender {
[self callFunction1];
[self callFunction2];
}
```

**The result will be the same.**

If this is not what you want to do then your action setup was incorrect to begin with. For one, which node is running the above action sequence doesn't actually matter, it will still run the selectors in the MyScene class instance.

Comment: - In 1st scene: I have some actions to run before I push to 2nd scene. So I used CCActionSequence. In callFunction2, I push to 2nd scene 

 - In 2nd sceen: I pop to 1st scene.
One thing I do not understand is why [self.myMenu runAction:sequence] not call CCActionCallFunc after I pop from 2nd scene

Comment: You're probably running the action on the menu of the already popped scene, thus it will not work correctly. Assuming you run the sequence on "current scene menu" but you push another scene directly afterwards, this particular action sequence may not run until you pop the scene. A similar problem exists if you pop a scene right after running an action. Again it'll be better if you just send messages to the appropriate scene and selector directly rather than relying on actions.